# Simple spring framework program not running and I cannot figure out why

Tags: java, spring

I have already had help with this program and got it to work. I then decided I would do it again my scratch to make sure I understood but I got the same issues. The hard part is the console is not printing out any errors.

console:

```
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:09 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:LearnSpringMVC' did not find a matching property.
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.17
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Jan 9 2015 15:58:59 UTC
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.0.17.0
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Mac OS X
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.10.2
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          x86_64
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JAVA_HOME:             /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_31-b13
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /apache-tomcat-8.0.17
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /apache-tomcat-8.0.17
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/apache-tomcat-8.0.17
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/apache-tomcat-8.0.17
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=/apache-tomcat-8.0.17/wtpwebapps
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/apache-tomcat-8.0.17/endorsed
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /Users/DrewJocham/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:09 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:09 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:09 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:09 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1890 ms
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.17
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:12 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [216] milliseconds.
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /apache-tomcat-8.0.17/webapps/docs
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:12 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /apache-tomcat-8.0.17/webapps/docs has finished in 194 ms
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /apache-tomcat-8.0.17/webapps/examples
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /apache-tomcat-8.0.17/webapps/examples has finished in 750 ms
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /apache-tomcat-8.0.17/webapps/host-manager
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:13 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /apache-tomcat-8.0.17/webapps/host-manager has finished in 164 ms
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /apache-tomcat-8.0.17/webapps/manager
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:13 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /apache-tomcat-8.0.17/webapps/manager has finished in 172 ms
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /apache-tomcat-8.0.17/webapps/ROOT
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:13 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /apache-tomcat-8.0.17/webapps/ROOT has finished in 147 ms
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:13 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:13 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Mar 22, 2015 9:07:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 4068 ms
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID"
    version="3.1">
    <display-name>SpringJSP</display-name>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:offers-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>offers</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>offers</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

home.jsp file

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello from JSP...
</body>
</html>
```

OffersController.java

```
package com.learnspring.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class OffersController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView homeGet(HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println("Check mapping");
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("home");
        return model;
    }
}
```

offers-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.learnspring.controller"></context:component-scan>
    <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />
    <bean
        id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property
            name="prefix"
            value="/WEB-INF/jsps/"></property>
        <property
            name="suffix"
            value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I do not know why this keeps happening to me. Can anyone help out? I checked the working code line by line and it was correct and it still works.

Comment: You forgot to describe *what* is the problem with this application.

Comment: Do you have any configuration fiels for spring (xml or java based)?

Comment: @kryger My problem is I get a 404 error when I run this application....

Comment: Did you declare a [springmvcname]-servlet.xml where you declare that you want to scan controller package when looking for resources?

Comment: I just updated the post. I forgot to add my offers-servlet.xml file

Comment: Are you trying to open it on `127.0.0.1:8080`?

Comment: Yet another case of incorrect *root-vs-servlet* context handling. Please remove your `ContextLoaderListener` from your web.xml.

Comment: @Santosh Karna sorry for my mistake of not writing the correct file name, it is named offers-servlet.xml.

@ Pavel Horal Are you saying delete the listener, or just the word ContextLoaderListener?

Answer (score 0):

your application context xml file name should be offers-servlet.xml in stead of offers.xml

Comment: sorry for my mistake of not writing the correct file name, it is named offers-servlet.xml.

Comment: @ Pavel Horal Are you saying delete the listener, or just the word ContextLoaderListener?

Comment: @Pavel Horal I deleted the the ContextLoader and then tried to delete the listener and it still did not work.

Comment: you can try this in your web.xml file                                                                                               <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/offers-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

Comment: and if you are using maven then you have to configure maven dependencies in your eclipse project

Comment: I triple checked the dependencies and put in your code and it still is not working. I am going on day 5 now. This is so frustrating!!!

Comment: I run your code in my eclipse. Initially it was not working but after setting context param as I said and setting dependecies on project,it worked succefully.

Comment: To set maven dependencies I followed this step  Right click on project then click on properties then click on deployment assembly then click on add then click on java build path entries then next then select maven dependencies then finish.after that run on server.for me it worked.hope after following this step it will work for you too

Comment: @ SantoshKarnaI have tried that before and I made you a youtube video to show you the issue with that, the maven option is not there.
https://youtu.be/ksYowsbg_C4

Comment: I am still having this issue. I have created the program several times and still am having the same problem. Please can anyone help.

Comment: you can find your runnable project here [link](https://github.com/santoshkarna/SpringTest.git). As I found your offers-servlet.xml and web.xml file in lib.you can compare your project with my project